# SMTPSendFailedException: Error Sending Mail using 1and1 mail service

Tags: java, spring, email, jakarta-mail

Previously I used to send and receive emails using `gmail` and the mail service works fine. Now I am switched to `1and1` mailing service.

**Configuration:**

```
Host: smtp.1and1.com
Port: 587
Username: xxxxx
Password: xxxxx
```

And I got following error while sending mails:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/mailtest] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 invalid sender domain 'Office' (misconfigured dns?) http://postmaster.1and1.com/error-messages/#invalidsenderdomain
; message exceptions (1) are:
Failed message 1: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 invalid sender domain 'Office' (misconfigured dns?) http://postmaster.1and1.com/error-messages/#invalidsenderdomain
] with root cause
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 invalid sender domain 'Office' (misconfigured dns?) http://postmaster.1and1.com/error-messages/#invalidsenderdomain
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 421 invalid sender domain 'Office' (misconfigured dns?) http://postmaster.1and1.com/error-messages/#invalidsenderdomain

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1515)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:416)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:306)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:296)
    at com.office.mailtest.mvc.component.EmailSender.sendEmail(EmailSender.java:29)
    at com.office.mailtest.mvc.controller.SignupController.sendConfirmationUsingGmail(SignupController.java:318)
    at com.office.mailtest.mvc.controller.SignupController.showSignupForm(SignupController.java:245)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:61)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:380)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Please check if you have configured DNS for 1and1. Also check if port for SMTP is open.

Comment: No, I haven't configured it. How can I configure DNS for 1and1? yeah SMTP port is open

Answer (score 0):

Seams that 1and1 is a bit more restrictive than your old gmail provider on your senders domain naming (as seen in the logfile 'Office' is realy not a valid domain name, isn't it?)

Comment: Actually Office is my Computer Name. If I have to configure domain name, How can I explicitly do that?

Comment: Ideally your computer would have a fully qualified DNS name, perhaps one assigned by DHCP.  If it does not, you can set whatever name you want to use in the SMTP connection by setting the [mail.stmp.localhost property](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html).